# how to see properties available for access with NEW plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Say I have a PLPGSQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name
RETURNS TRIGGER AS ...
BEGIN
   PERFORM
      1
   FROM
      table1 t1
   JOIN
      table2 t2 USING( column_name )
   WHERE
      t1.column_name = NEW.column_name;
   RETURN NEW;
END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name
   ON table1;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   BEFORE INSERT ON table1
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_name;
```

1. I noticed that only some columns in `table1` and `table2` are accessible with `NEW.column_name`. How can I see the full list of columns I can access with `NEW`?
2. Additionally, if there is a column in `table1` or `table2` that I cannot access with `NEW`, how can I make it accessible to `NEW`?

Comment: What is the trigger triggering on? Is it row level? What table is the trigger applied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
```

This tells you that the trigger is executed before an `INSERT ON table1`. This means that you will have `NEW.`column_name for any column of `table1`, while `table2` is unchanged by the trigger and makes no sense to use `OLD` or `NEW` on it, hence it illegal. So, to be precise: `NEW` works for `table1` columns and does not work on `table2` columns.